# Best way to load uncertain no. of images in incremented order Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm creating a book with chapters. Chapters have pages in pieces in .jpg format in the network. The no. of pages in a chapter are uncertain for that I've created a function(code below) to create a chapter with images.

**Problem with my implementation:**

1. All 100 images are trying to load at the same time and most of the time initial pages are loaded later(creates confusion to readers). How do I make sure to load images as ordered in the list? (First image first, then second, then third and so on..). I know lazy loading libraries are to solve but I'm not sure about the implementation in this case and which one is more appropriate.
2. Since the no. of pages in a chapter are uncertain, below code adds all created 100 images URLs in the list (this way even invalid URLs till 100 are also trying to load). I don't want to call invalid URLs every time users scroll down.

Code :

```
createChapter(int chapterNumber){
String imageUrl;
for(int i=1; i<100; i++){
  imageUrl = 'https://www.someurl.com/chapter1/'+i+'.jpg';
  print(imageUrl);
  bookList.add(
    CachedNetworkImage(
      imageUrl: imageUrl,
      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
    ));
}
}

=======================

ListView(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        children: bookList,
      ),
```

I know the above code doesn't make enough sense for what I am trying to achieve. I'd like to know the best implementation for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

`ListView.builder` allows you to specify a number of items and a builder function. 
The builder function is passed the context and each item index and then builds each item. This is often used to build lists of unknown (or infinite) length.

Here is a more concrete example for your use case:

```dart
ListView.builder(
  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
  itemCount: numberOfPages,
  itemBuilder: (context, index){
    imageUrl = 'https://www.someurl.com/chapter1/'+index+'.jpg';
    print(imageUrl);
    return CachedNetworkImage(
      imageUrl: imageUrl,
      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
    );
  }
)
```

In this example, you have to find the number of pages in each chapter ahead of time and store it in the `numberOfPages` variable.

Comment: `numberOfPages` is the actual problem here. These are uncertain and differs by every chapter. Hence I'm looking for a solution where I call them in incrementing order and keeps displaying them until I get error.